# Can you identify this medieval glyph?

Tags: medieval-latin

In the attached image from a medieval Florentine manuscript, what is the character/abbreviation after "donavit"?  There also seems to be a version of it in the word before "ecclesiam".  Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess would be *pro* and *prope*.

This particular backwards hook, starting at the top of the descender, can mean "ro," as discussed [here](https://www.nottingham.ac.uk/manuscriptsandspecialcollections/researchguidance/medievaldocuments/letterformsandabbreviations.aspx).

Wikimedia has a few examples in [this category](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Scribal_abbreviations):

[image: quia pro] ([quia pro](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Confessiones-UBU_Hs._41-Inscriptie_van_Hector_van_Moerdrecht_(cropped)_-_Scribal_abbreviation_%22q_p%22_for_%22quia_pro%22.jpg))

[image: prope] ([prope](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Confessiones-UBU_Hs._41-Inscriptie_van_Hector_van_Moerdrecht_(cropped)_-_Scribal_abbreviation_%22ppe%22_for_%22prope%22.jpg))

[image: prophete] ([prophete](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Excerpt_from_ms._19160_of_the_BnF,_page_121,_3th_column_(cropped)_-_Scribal_abbreviation_%22pphete%22_for_%22prophete%22.jpg))

Comment: Thank you!  Could I ask you how you would translate it (up to carta man. Rodulfi)?  I think it is saying Borgo Santi Apostoli (a neighborhood) was destroyed and as a remedy Bishop Raniero (something something) near the church of Santi Apostoli?  Or should I put this in a new question?

Comment: The phrase is “pro remedio”